# what kind of certificate do I have to use on fortinet proxy so the clients would trust it without further configuration?

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate

What kind of certificate do we have to install on fortinet proxy so https connections are trusted by clients on the internal network (*)?

(*) Without installing the certificate on clients.

[image: Firefox showing "Your connection is not trusted error"]

We are looking for an affordable certificate that clients would automatically trust and pass thru the fortinet proxy without further configuration.

I am looking on the certificates on https://www.ssls.com/ but not sure which one to buy that would work the way we want.

The clients include:

- Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer
- The Java runtime (which has an exclusive certificate keystore)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

In short: there is no way to do what you want.

You would need to install a CA certificate in the proxy which is already trusted by the clients, i.e. one which was issued by a public CA. While it was sometimes common in the past to get such certificates fortunately today CA's can get publicly distrusted in the browsers if they issue such certificates so you will not get such thing.

Apart from that even if you would get such a thing it will cause problems with connections using certificate pinning, i.e. google, facebook etc. Since SSL interception will change the certificate the browser will complain that the certificate does not match any longer and deny access. Pinning is only automatically disabled by the browsers if the new certificate is issued by none of the default CA's and if this new CA was explicitly added as trusted.

Comment: he should actually install an intermediate certificates,  not the CA

Comment: @JacobEvans: an intermediate certificate is a CA certificate, only not a root CA certificate (in detail: Basic constraints CA:True must be set for both). But, no public CA should issue such an intermediate certificate for the purpose of SSL interception today and if they do they risk to be banned from the browsers.

Comment: couldn't agree more,  good clarification